# Program spitting out wrong answer - Project Euler

Tags: c#, math, console

I've been working on Project Euler (question #8).

> Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

I wrote a relatively simple program to find any consecutive digits. The program loops through each digit in a character array containing each number as an element. Inside the for loop, I compared the following four numbers after the current position to see it was a consecutive digit. From my understanding, the number 8527 would meet the criteria because 7 precedes the number 8.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string number = "731671...52963450";

        char[] numCharArray = number.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < numCharArray.Length - 5; i++)
        {
            string n1Str = numCharArray[i + 1].ToString();
            string n2Str = numCharArray[i + 2].ToString();
            string n3Str = numCharArray[i + 3].ToString();
            string n4Str = numCharArray[i + 4].ToString();
            string iStr = numCharArray[i].ToString();

            int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(n1Str);
            int n2 = Convert.ToInt32(n2Str);
            int n3 = Convert.ToInt32(n3Str);
            int n4 = Convert.ToInt32(n4Str);
            int iNum = Convert.ToInt32(iStr);

            int prod = iNum * n1 * n2 * n3 * n4 ;

            //I believe this is the source of the problem
            if (iNum == n1 + 1 || iNum == n2 + 1 || iNum == n3 + 1 || iNum == n4 + 1 || iNum == n1 - 1 || iNum == n2 - 1 || iNum == n3 - 1 || iNum == n4 - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prod);
            }

        }
```

Anyway, *please don't write a new approach to this for me.* I would just like to know why I'm not getting the correct answer.

By the way, the program has an `IndexOutOfRangeException` and it gives you all the "answers" but I'll fix this once I implement the logic for the program to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with this bit of code, but it would really surprise me if this would ever spit out the right answer.

```
if (iNum == n1 + 1 || iNum == n2 + 1 || iNum == n3 + 1 || iNum == n4 + 1 || iNum == n1 - 1 || iNum == n2 - 1 || iNum == n3 - 1 || iNum == n4 - 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prod);
}
```

I hope you won't consider this a new approach, but here's what I would suggest.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string number = "731671...52963450";

    char[] numCharArray = number.ToCharArray();
    int maxProduct = 0; // initial value

    for (int i = 0; i < numCharArray.Length - 5 /* Fix IndexOutOfRange (see Matthew Fahrbach's answer) */; i++)
    {
        // ...

        int prod = iNum * n1 * n2 * n3 * n4;
        if (prod > maxProd)
        {
            maxProd = prod;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(maxProd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop reaches the final index of your array, but you are then indexing four elements after the last index. This is the reason for your IndexOutOfRangeException. Try the following instead,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numCharArray.Length - 5; i++)
```

Comment: Yes that's why I want to add another if statement to avoid that or modify the for statement. But for the meantime, I'm just trying to get the right answer.

Comment: I added ' - 5' to it. Solves the IndexOutOfRange exception.

Answer (score 1):

Having solved that problem, It looks like you misunderstood what "consecutive digits" means in this context. I recall that consecutive here means "in a row". So consider each set of 5 digits, 73167, then 31671, etc. There should be roughly 996 such sets of five digits. Find the largest product of those digits out of all of those sets.